# Number of rays on finite grid?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> Let's have a set $M = \{ (i,j) : i,j \in \{0,\dots,m\}\}$. Define equivalence on $M$, $(i,j) \sim (k,l)$ iff there is $r \in \mathbb R$ that $(ri,rj) = (k,l)$.
>
> Question is what is the number of elements of $M/_\sim$?

---

Motivation:

This is math/programming question. I have a grid of points $(i,j)$ for $i,j\in \{0,\dots,m-1\}$. Now I want to evaluate function $f(i,j)$ for all $i,j$ and I want to do it fast. The thing is that I can calculate $f$ easily along a ray. So if I calculate $f(i,j)$ than I can calculate $f(2i,2j)$ fast and than I can calculate $f(3i,3j)$ fast etc.

The question sounds a little bit like the question about the size of projective plane over finite field but it isn't.

Comment: It seems you aren't so much interested in the number of rays, as in efficiently enumerating the rays. If that is the case, a traversal of the Stern-Brocot or the Calkin-Wilf tree to get the pairs $(i,\,j)$ of coprime integers with $i,\, j \leqslant m$ could be what you want.

Comment: well, I thought if I can calculate number of ray than I get some insight so I will be able to traverse them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each ray not above the diagonal (so with $i\geq j$) has as slope a fraction $0\leq\frac ji\leq1$ with denominator at most$~n$. The list of all such fractions is the $n$-th [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) and its length is called the $n$-th [Farey number](http://oeis.org/A005728), which equals $1+\sum_{i=1}^n\phi(i)$ where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function (there are $\phi(i)$ nonzero reduced fractions${}\leq1$ with denominator$~i$). For the number you ask for, add as many minus one for the rays above the diagonal, giving $1+2\sum_{i=1}^n\phi(i)$.